# receive in flask json converted and form data

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, form-data

I have a API in flask. The objetive is to receive a converted csv file (function in javascript) and form data in flask separate. Form data is metadata and csv file converted to json is data.
I'm only getting the form data, the json file i'm getting none.

My json converted from csv file it's store in variable result and form data is stored in formdata. I send the two variable separated. I'm receiving all the data that i insert in HTML. The JSON that result from a function that convert csv files to json i'm not getting in flask side.

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">         
    <title>Register</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/sendform.js"> </script> 
    <link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/mainpage.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">     
  </head>          
  <body>
    <div id="upper_left"></div>
      <div id="upper_right"></div>
      <div id="lower_left"></div>
      <div id="lower_right"></div> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Metadados - Dados relacionados com o Atleta</div>   
      <form action="index" method="post">
        <div class="user-details">
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Nome Completo</span>
            <input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Introduza o nome completo do atleta">
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Data de Nascimento</span>
            <input type="text" name="birthdate" placeholder="Introduza a data de nascimento do atleta">
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Altura</span>
            <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Introduza a altura do atleta em cm">
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Peso</span>
            <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Introduza o peso do atleta em kg">
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Tamanho da Piscina</span>
            <input type="text" name="poolsize" placeholder="Introduza o tamanho da piscina">
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Modalidade</span>
            <input type="text" name="modality" placeholder="Introduza a modalidade">
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Estilo(s) de Natação</span>
            <input type="text" name="swimStyle" placeholder="Introduza o estilo(s) de natação">
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Género</span>
            <select name="gender">
              <option value ="gender">Selecionar genéro</option>
              <option value ="masculino">Masculino</option>
              <option value ="feminino">Feminino</option>
            </select> 
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Escalão Etário</span>
            <select name="gender-title">
              <option value ="gender-title">Select gender group</option>
              <option value ="Escola_de_natacao">ESCOLA DE NATACAO</option>
              <option value ="grupos_de_natacao_desportiva">GRUPOS DE FORMACAO DESPORTIVA</option>
              <option value ="cadeteA">CADETES A</option>
              <option value ="cadeteB">CADETES B</option>
              <option value ="infatilB">INFANTIS B</option>
              <option value ="infatilA">INFANTIS A</option>
              <option value ="juvenilB">JUVENIS B</option>
              <option value ="juvenilA">JUVENIS A</option>
              <option value ="junior">JUNIORES</option>
              <option value ="senior">SENIORES</option>
            </select>                   
          </div>
          <div class="title">Metadados Envio de dados</div> 
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Utilizador Id</span>
            <input type="text" name="userId" placeholder="Introduza o seu Id">
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Token</span>
            <input type="text" name="token" placeholder="Introduza o token">
          </div>
          <p>Selecionar o ficheiro localmente:</p>
          <input name="myFile" type="file" accept=".txt,.xlsx, .xls, .csv" > 
          <div class="button">            
            <input type="submit" id="btn-post" value="Enviar dados" onclick="do_ajax();"> 
            <div class="input-box"></dix>           
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function do_ajax() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input').files;
  if(!input.length){
    alert("No file selected");
    return;
  } 
  var file = input[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function() {
    return function(e) {
      var fileData = e.target.result.trim().split('\n').map(row => row.split(','));      
      var HEADERS = ["time", "yaw", "pitch", "roll", "heading", "ax", "ay", "az", "gx", "gy", "gz", "mx", "my", "mz"];      
      const RESULT = {};
      // Assign every heading to the result.
      for (const HEADING of HEADERS) RESULT[HEADING] = [];
      fileData.map(row =>
          // Each row → each column, number of columns === number of headers
          row.map((column, i) =>
            RESULT[HEADERS[i]]
            .push(Number(column))
          ));
        console.log(RESULT);        
      };
  })(file);
    reader.readAsText(file);;       
    let fullName = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
    let birthdate = document.getElementById('birthdate').value;
    let height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    let weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    let poolsize = document.getElementById('poolsize').value;
    let modality = document.getElementById('modality').value;
    let swimStyle = document.getElementById('swimStyle').value;
    var tel = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    var sel = document.getElementById('gender-title').value;
    console.log(sel.value);    
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("fullName", fullName)
    formdata.append("birthdate",birthdate)
    formdata.append("weight",weight)    
    formdata.append("height",height) 
    formdata.append("poolsize",poolsize) 
    formdata.append("modality",modality)
    formdata.append("swimStyle",swimStyle)
    formdata.append("gender",tel)
    formdata.append("gender-title",sel) 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/index', true);
    xhr.send(formdata);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(RESULT));  
  };
```

```
FLASK

from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pymongo
import json



app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])  
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form["fullName"]
        birthdate =request.form["birthdate"]
        poolsize =request.form["poolsize"]
        height =request.form["height"]
        weight =request.form["weight"]
        modality =request.form["modality"]
        swimStyle =request.form["swimStyle"]
        gender = request.form["gender"]
        gender_title = request.form["gender-title"]
        output = request.get_json()
        print(output)
        print (name,birthdate,poolsize,height,weight,modality,swimStyle)
        alldata = { "sessionData": output,
                   "metadata":{ "birthdate": birthdate, "Name": name, 
                                "Weight": height,"Pool_size":poolsize, 
                                "Weight":weight,"Gender":gender,"Gender_title":gender_title,
                                "modality":modality, "swimStyle": swimStyle}}        
        return alldata,200
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't send formdata and json together in 1 HTTP POST request. Could you comment out "xhr.send(formdata);" and try to retrieve json?

Comment: I've tested. Still can't get the json :( . I can send two HTTP POST request?

Comment: You need this when you send json "xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');"
If this is not the problem, you can check raw data with this "print(request.get_data())"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A data transfer can only conform to one format. This formatting is either an encoding for a form or corresponds to JSON formatting.

You can still send the data within one request.
Either you add the JSON-formatted data as a field to the form, or you convert the form data into a JSON structure.

With the first variant, it is necessary to read the JSON data manually on the server side. You can use the python [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library for this. For the latter, the framework does this work.
A third option is to transfer the file within the form and simply read it on the server side.

Whichever option you choose, don't forget to validate the inputs.

In the following example, all form data is converted to JSON and sent to the server. I shortened the code a bit for clarity.
The version of adding JSON formatted data to the form data should be self-explanatory.
I think the best solution is to read the file server side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Read CSV to JSON</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="my-form" method="post" enctype="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <!-- ... -->
      <input type="file" name="csv" allow="text/csv" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      ((uri) => {

        function readCSV(file, delim=',') {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onerror = reject;
            reader.onload = (evt) => {
              resolve(evt.target.result.split(/\r\n|\n/).map(line => line.split(delim)));
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
          });
        }

        function serialize(formData) {
          const data = {};
          for (const [k, v] of formData) data[k] = v;
          return data;
        }

        // Register a listener for submit events and suppress the default behavior of the form.
        const form = document.querySelector('form[name="my-form"]');
        form.addEventListener('submit', async evt => {
          evt.preventDefault();

          if(!evt.target.csv.files.length) {
            alert('No file selected.');
            return;
          }

          const file = evt.target.csv.files[0];
          const formData = new FormData(evt.target);
          formData.delete('csv');
          // Conversion of the form data into an object.
          const data = serialize(formData);
          // Reading and converting the file into a list of objects.
          // Adding the list to the previous object.
          data['csv'] = await readCSV(file, ',')
            .then(csv => {
              const head = ['time', 'yaw', 'pitch', 'roll', 'heading', 'ax',
                            'ay', 'az', 'gx', 'gy', 'gz', 'mx', 'my', 'mz'];
              return csv.map(row => {
                let r = {};
                row.forEach((col, i) => r[head[i]] = Number(col));
                return r;
              });
            });

          // Sending the JSON data to the server.
          fetch(uri, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          }).then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
        });

      })({{ url_for('.data') | tojson }});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import (
    jsonify,
    render_template,
    request,
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def data():
    data = request.json
    print(data)
    return jsonify(success=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sharing. Understand now that i can't send two requests at same time. I'm getting this error in javascript - property assignment excepted . Can you help me. Thanks a lot again. best regards

Comment: @youngt17 There is an error in the assignment to a variable. Unfortunately I can't tell you more about it. So far the error has not occurred for me.

Comment: this part : ({{ url_for('.data') | tojson }}); i have to put my localhost:5000/data ? thanks a lot for your patient

Comment: @youngt17 The line generates the URL to your endpoint to send the data to and passes it to the JavaScript function. The name of the function is passed to `url_for`. The URL then results from the rule for the endpoint and is converted to JSON to set the necessary quotation marks. So you can change the name of the endpoint if you then customize this line as well. This is a jinja directive and cannot be used in an external js file. ([`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.url_for), [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson))

Comment: @youngt17 Of course, you can also pass a hard-coded address. "http:localhost:5000/data" or "/data" can be passed as a string.

Comment: i discover where the error's come from. I have the separate javascript file , thanks :)

Comment: @youngt17 It might be the destructuring assignment inside the for loop in `serialize`. But I am not sure. If the error is there you can just use `formData.forEach((value, key) => data[key] = value);` .

Comment: one more question my function in javascript parse the csv like this:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241989/discussion-between-detlef-and-youngt17).